# Asp.Net Core Custom Tag Helpers for Select Lists - Asp-Items appears to be executing twice

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have authored a simple select tag helper to perform field disabling when a model condition is met. However when it is applied to the Razor View it appears to be executing the built in asp-items tag helper twice (and adding the same list twice) when the view renders. Any help would be appreciated.

The offending Tag Helper

```
[HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = "asp-disabled")]
public class DisabledSelectTagHelper : SelectTagHelper
{
    public DisabledSelectTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator) {}

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-disabled")]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Disabled)
            output.Attributes.Add("disabled", null);

        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

Tag Helper in View

```
<div class="col-xs-4 padding-top-sm">
    <label asp-for="CreditCardVendor" class="inline"></label>
    <select asp-for="CreditCardVendor" asp-items="ViewBag.CreditCardVendors" class="form-control" asp-disabled="Model.UpdateCreditCardExpirationOnly"></select>   
</div>
```

The _ViewImports.cshtml file

```
@using UI
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, UI
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Is that your full Razor View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to not invoke the base.Process() method. Inspecting the TagHelperOutput parameter during debugging is what showed me that the result of asp-items had already been executed and explicitly invoking the method caused asp-items to re-execute.

Comment: Careful with not doing the base.Process(context, output) - it will not render the other attributes of the select that you would expect such as id, name, etc which may not be what you want